# Can WCF RIA Services be self hosted?

Tags: wcf, wcf-ria-services, self-hosting

I know WCF can be self hosted. how about WCF RIA Services? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it can be self-hosted after small configuration:

```
DomainServiceHost host = new DomainServiceHost(typeof(DomainService1), uri);
host.Description.Behaviors.Remove<AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute>();
```

Answer (score 1):

WCF RIA Services is build on top of WCF and they get exposed as WCF services. 
See [WCF RIA Services on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707344%28VS.91%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this forum thread on MSDN](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/182302/413287.aspx), it is not possible to do such thing because RIA services set the ASP.NET compatibility to be required, therefore needing the IIS hosting.