# Out Of Browser Silverlight app with local offline database and WCF-RIA

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, out-of-browser

I have the following scenario:

We develop a silverlight 4 app for our customers, that will be used as an out-of-browser app. The app is working offline, i.e. app and database are on the users local machine. The app is using WCF-RIA-services to connect to the local database. The database will be an SQL Server Express, SQL Server CE or MySQL. We are using MVVMLight and MEF.

An external webserver is only used for updating the app from time to time or adding new modules to the app. To achieve this we do something similar as shown in Jeremy Likness blog (http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/05/25/silverlight-out-of-browser-dynamic-modules-in-offline-mode.aspx )

The reasons why we are doing such a scenario are complex. But to keep a long story short it is mainly for compatibility reasons for a later online version and we don't want to use WPF. So we need to get this working with Silverlight and WCF-RIA services.

Ok, that's the scenario and here's the question:

Do we need a local webserver in this scenario? The app is programmatically installed as out-of-browser, the database is local and connected via WCF-RIA.

If yes, which webserver would be sufficient? It should be installed and configured via an initial setup that is executed by the customer. The customer should not have to do anything with configuring the webserver.

Any other ideas or comments on this scenario? Any other possible solutions for this?

Thanks for your help
Dirk

Answer (score 0):

silverlight wasn't meant to be used this way I think. So it would be like when you are developing app in visual studio and use Cassini to see result - everything runs locally - but you still need a web server. Maybe more info here - http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/06/WPF-vs-Silverlight

Comment: We want to use our SL4 app offline. As far as we got now, we try to setup a scenario with IIS Express and SL4 with a WCF-RIA service (as we would do with a 'normal' remoteserver). This works well if VS 2010 is running, but not when we try to start the app and the IIS server when VS 2010 is not running.

Answer (score 0):

I´m not able to provide with a full answer to your problem, as we are currently facing the same problem. (WPF not being cross-platform, Very specific hardware on some clients)

But I may share some of our thoughts on our type of Thick-Silverlight-Client:

1. To keep deployment etc. simple we use a self-hosting process (installed as background process)
2. We may not use RIA as the background process has to run using Mono VM (but for MS-only solution see [Can WCF RIA Services be self hosted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598445/can-wcf-ria-services-be-self-hosted) )

Architectural thoughts on standalone "Clients":

Depending on your requirements implementing a server for each client communicating with the "main"-server by messages (NServiceBus) may be overkill. But if you want to use a client database if offline and silverlight for ui you should consider using an event-driven-architecture.

There is a slideshow on combining "Event-Driven-Architecture" & "CQRS" with Silverlight. But i would not use it as a blueprint more like an inspiration.
http://www.slideshare.net/dennisdoomen/cqrs-and-event-sourcing-an-alternative-architecture-for-ddd