# WCF RIA Service hosted outside IIS

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a need to host WCF RIA Services outside IIS on a client machine. After reading the following threads:

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/182302/413287.aspx
[Can WCF RIA Services be self hosted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598445/can-wcf-ria-services-be-self-hosted)
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/213861/512468.aspx
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/silverlightdeveloper/thread/804341f3-9f1e-420b-9cdc-c1334bd9302f

I gave up on that idea due to the "AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute" that RIA Service uses and started researching alternative solutions.

However, just yesterday I read more about Visual Studio LightSwitch and the fact that uses WCF RIA Services internally. With LightSwitch, you can deploy your appliction in a 2-tier scenario on the desktop that gets installed using ClickOnce and runs as a Silverlight out-of-browser application that can access data without connectiong to IIS.

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Lightswitch uses Visual Studio's Cassini server in the 2-tier scenario. I don't know much more about how it's hosted. In summary, it's still an ASP.NET compatible environment but this time with dependencies on Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your answer implies Visual Studio dependency during development, but it seems rather unlikely for the compiled application that will be installed on various client desktops to have dependency on Visual Studio.